# How to convert tar.bz2 to .bz2?

Tags: tar, compression

I have a file with compression tar.bz2 , I would like to convert it to .bz2 . Is there a command that does this in one shot?

I tried the below but no joy !

```
 tar -xvjf US.tar.bz2
 US

 bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
         perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
 bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
         Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

 It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
 You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

 You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
 data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

 tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
 tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
```

P.S.

I tried the bellow as well:

bunzip2 -c < US.tar.bz2 | gzip -c > us.bz2

which yields:

```
bunzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
    perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bunzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.
```

Comment: I'm confused. You want to take a (possibly corrupted) compressed tar file and convert it to ... a compressed file? If there is more than one file in the tarball, you're out of luck.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller thank you for clarifying. I thought I am running the command incorrectly but it looks like the file I am decompressing is corrupted!

Comment: Try uncompressing it first, with bunzip, to see if it is corrupted.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller thanks for suggesting, it is indeed corrupted.

Comment: Is the file in fact compressed at all? What does `file US.tar.bz2` report?

Answer (score 1):

`tar` is like a zip file that stores a bunch of other files, but doesn't compress them.  `bzip2` compresses a file, but only one at a time.  A `.tar.bz2` file likely indicates a bunch of files were put in a `tar` and subsequently zipped.  You can't zip them together without tarring them, first.

Your error is because your `.tar.bz2` file is corrupt.  See an example of a properly working file below.

```
$ ls
test_file.tar.bz2
$ tar xvjf test_file.tar.bz2 
test_file
$ ls
test_file  test_file.tar.bz2
```

---

EDIT

---

In the above example, there was only one file in the tar.  If you want to zip just that folder:

```
$ bzip2 test_file
$ ls
test_file.bz2
```

Comment: then re-compress 'test_file' to 'test_file.bz2'

Comment: @mehany, you can only do this if the original `.tar.bz2` file had a single zipped file inside.  If so, the edit demonstrates how to zip it without tarring.